# maximum number of polynomial solutions mod p^e

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$, it has at most $n$ roots mod $p$. Hensel's lemma then says each root can be lifted to a unique solution mod $p^2$ if $f'(r) \not\equiv 0 (mod p)$. Thus there are at most $n$ roots mod $p^2$, and we can keep going to reason there are at most $n$ roots mod $p^e$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes but only under the assumption $f'(r)\not\equiv0\pmod p$. That's important, as examples like $f(x) = x^n$ modulo $p^n$ show.

Comment: Right, so if $f'(r) \equiv 0 (mod p)$ then this root $r$ could lead to multiple roots $p^e$, however, if all roots $f'(r) \not\equiv 0 (mod p)$ then it is safe to say there's the same number of roots mod $p$ and mod $p^e$